# Can I remove document.getElementById in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, debugging, refactoring

Can I change the prop `value` without

```
document.getElementById(objRef.uid + "_size" ).value = val
```

note that these dropdowns are being made in a for loop, and there are thousands of them.

```
<DropDownMenu 
    id={objRef.uid + "_size"} 
    setValue={( val ) => { document.getElementById( objRef.uid + "_size" ).value = val }} 
    value={objRef.size} 
    colors={["bg-red-500", "bg-yellow-400", "bg-emerald-400"]} 
    options={["Small", "Medium", "Large"]} />
```

Comment: Yes, you can remove it in reactJS. Can you show your full code or make a runnable short snippet. you can use codesandbox.io if you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can.
you can use the useRef hook.

example of using it (you can remember that each HTML element get a ref properties that you an implement a value in it, in example you see an input element but it is the same for div and more)

```
 function App() {
  const inputElement = useRef();

  const focusInput = () => {
    inputElement.current.focus();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" ref={inputElement} />
      <button onClick={focusInput}>Focus Input</button>
    </>
  );
}
```